# jqGrid not working in IE7, 8, 9 but it works when use F12

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jqgrid, cross-browser

My jqGrid not showing in IE7, 8, 9 at all.

**HOWEVER, IT WORKS ONLY WHEN I TURN ON THE F12(DEVELOPER MODE IN IE)!**

Of course I cannot check console log because when I use F12 it works fine...

It may not about jQuery problem because my jQuery version is 1.7.

jqGrid version 4.4.3, and jqGrid works well in IE10, 11.

(I tried to change jqGrid version, but there are no any positive effects.)

Anybody know about this problem?

**What is the difference between using or not using F12???**

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work in those versions of IE? Not that you should care, since IE has been discontinued for a while now.

Comment: @StackSlave Because I can change default IE versions with my web server config. And I must care of older IE versions because my project is about old financial system...

Comment: IE is a Client-side Web Browser. Maybe there's something wrong with that server config.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. This was because of `console.log();` in my js code.

`console.log();` only works when F12 developer tools opened.

I removed this code, so it works.